# Mostrar/Ocular DIV segun opcion seleccionada (SELECT OPTION)

Tags: javascript, php, select

Tengo la siguiente problemática. Tengo el siguiente Select Option:

```
<?php
     $consulta = "SELECT id, codigo, nombre, AR FROM imputables
     WHERE id_cl = '$id_cl' AND estado = 'S' AND empresa = '$emp'";
     $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
       echo "<select class='form-control select2' style='width: 100%;' name='tc' id='tc' required>";
       echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>CUENTA</option>";
         while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
           //$AR[] = $row['AR'];
           echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['codigo']. " --> " .utf8_encode(strtoupper($row['nombre']))."</option>";
        }
        echo '</select>';
?>
```

Dicha consulta, se realiza a una tabla llamada imputables, donde existe un campo llamado AR:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, este campo puede tener S o N según lo que el usuario haya ingresado. Si se selecciona una opción del SELECT OPTION se debería verificar (a través del ID) el campo AR y ver si es S o N. Si es S, debería mostrarme un div que contiene unos INPUT. Si la Opción seleccionada es N, no debería mostrar ese div.

La verdad, estoy bastante perdido en como poder lograr eso. Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientación al respecto para poder solucionar este problema.

Saludos.

Comment: Y por que no agregar en el `WHERE` una condición para que solo retorne AR='N' ?

Comment: @rpaillao porque ambas opciones se pueden usar. No solamente N o S ya que ambas opciones se utilizan para diferentes motivos. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría con jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#el_id_de_tu_select").change(function () {// con el evento change detecto cuando seleccione una opcion.
var indice = document.tu_select.selectedIndex;//obtengo el indice seleccionado
var valor = document.tu_select.options[indice].text;//le paso el indice y obtengo el valor la fila   
if(mi condicion){
si mi condicion se cumple
}else{
si mi condicion no se cumple
});
```

espero te sirve de algo....

Comment: muchas gracias estimado, hare algunas pruebas basandome en tu propuesta y comento. saludos